# Issue with logging to code signed android app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have cordova-android 3.7.1. In debug mode of the the ionic android app it is working fine. But if I code sign the release build the app is not allowing to login. Looks like some issue with cordova-android 3.7.1 with REST service.

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: can you please add your error to question ?

Comment: actually it is not showing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from the below stackoverflow link.

[No internet access in signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011632/no-internet-access-in-signed-apk)

It is actually the problem with the SSL certificates Chain Issue

[image]

You can check your url for the above issue using the below site

https://www.ssllabs.com

Thanks